# What options are available to align door's knob and lock to door frame

Tags: doors

A  rarely used exterior door mortise and tenon does not align.  Although the door closes, the doorknob's tenon does not enter its mortise. The same is true for the deadbolt. The tenons shown in the photo is low relative to the mortise.

What options are there to enable the door to lock?

I am considering a new slab door, however, I am hoping for a quicker, cost effective solution.

[image]

Comment: One presumes that this rarely used door was left in the closed position, not the open position. Therefore, when you opened it, the door sagged. To close, simply lift the handle until the latches line up properly, then leave it closed for a long time, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough to move the strike plates to algn. You may have to increase the size of the mortise with a wood chisel. Fill the old holes using toothpicks or a small dowel and wood glue. Then reset the strike plates.
It's about as cost effective as you can get.
Another option I've used is to install a hinge spacer on the bottom hinge to raise the door up slightly. You can get them at most home stores. Obviously, you need enough play around the door to accomodate the movement.

Comment: This solution was effective and enabled locking the door.  Thank you

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer helped you please show by an upvote or a check as an accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: This answer was effective in this situation and thus awarded the "accepted answer".  Solution was simple and cost effective

Answer (score 2):

I have mostly solid core doors and since we built the house several have "sagged" and won't latch. A trick my contractor told me about is to use long (like 3.5" - 4") screws  to replace 2-3 screws in the top hinge, tighten them down good and "pull back" the jam to the rough opening.  Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't.

I don't have a torque spec for you (or me!) so when I don't, I use the German scale:  "guut 'n tight" .  Just make sure you get high quality screws bc if you break one...ouch.

Comment: Good suggestion: we tried the today but ultimately had to increase the mortise with a wood chisel and lower the strike plate.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. Glad you tried it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I did this on almost every door in a 1950s house.  A chisel will get the job done.

I chose to move some of my doorknobs instead of their strike plates.  I figured if I screwed up really badly, I would rather struggle through repairing the door than the frame.  This was also a good opportunity to update the door hardware to modern smart locks.  To do this, you really should have a hole saw kit and a power drill with a side handle.

It helps to have a door knob installation jig (clamps onto the door and helps you drill in the correct position for today's standard doorknobs).  I did a few doors before I learned they exist.  It's a time-saver but not a requirement.
[image]